# Prove sequence converges if only some subsequences converge to the same limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I want to show that given $ (x_n) $ is a sequence of real numbers, if the subsequences $ (x_{3k}), (x_{3k+1}), (x_{3k+2}) $ converge to the same limit then the sequence $ (x_n) $ is convergent. How should one go about proving this?

I know that generally if all possible subsequences of $ (x_n) $ converge to the same limit then the sequence $ (x_n) $ converges as well. Can I prove the above with the fact that the subsequences $ (3k+2), (3k+1), (3k) $ form a partition of $ \mathbb{N} $ or something along these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Use what you say you know by remarking that $\;\{3k\}\;,\;\;\{3k+1\}\;,\;\;\{3k+2\}\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ is a partition of the natural numbers, and thus this means that: if $\;L\;$ is the common limit of those three subsequences, then for all $\;\epsilon >0\;$ there exist $\;N_0, N_1,N_2\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. that if $\;n\ge\max (N_0,N_1,N_2)\;$ , then

$$|x_n-L|<\epsilon\;\;\ldots$$